# group dataframe if the column has the same value in consecutive order

Tags: pandas, dataframe

let's say I have a dataframe that looks like below:

[image]

I want to assign my assets to one group if I have treatment that are consecutive. If there are two consecutive assets without treatment after them, then we still can assign them to the same group. However, if there are more than two assets without treatment, then those assets (without treatment) will have empty group. The next assets that have treatment will be assigned to a new group
[image]

Comment: Post image as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `rolling` check if whether there was at least one Y in the last N occurrences.

I am providing two options depending on whether or not it's important not to label the leading/trailing Ns:

```
# maximal number of days without treatment
# to remain in same group
N = 2

m = df['Treatment'].eq('Y')

group = m.rolling(N+1, min_periods=1).max().eq(0)
group = (group & ~group.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum().add(1)

df['group'] = group

# don't label leading/trailing N
m1 = m.groupby(group).cummax()
m2 = m[::-1].groupby(group).cummax()
df['group2'] = group.where(m1&m2)

print(df)
```

To handle the last NaNs separately:

```
m3 = ~m[::-1].cummax()
df['group3'] = group.where(m1&m2|m3)
```

Output:

```
   Treatment  group  group2  group3
0          Y      1     1.0     1.0
1          Y      1     1.0     1.0
2          Y      1     1.0     1.0
3          N      1     1.0     1.0
4          N      1     1.0     1.0
5          Y      1     1.0     1.0
6          Y      1     1.0     1.0
7          Y      1     1.0     1.0
8          N      1     NaN     NaN
9          N      1     NaN     NaN
10         N      2     NaN     NaN
11         Y      2     2.0     2.0
12         Y      2     2.0     2.0
13         Y      2     2.0     2.0
14         Y      2     2.0     2.0
15         N      2     NaN     2.0
```

Other example for `N=1`:

```
   Treatment  group  group2  group3
0          Y      1     1.0     1.0
1          Y      1     1.0     1.0
2          Y      1     1.0     1.0
3          N      1     NaN     NaN
4          N      2     NaN     NaN
5          Y      2     2.0     2.0
6          Y      2     2.0     2.0
7          Y      2     2.0     2.0
8          N      2     NaN     NaN
9          N      3     NaN     NaN
10         N      3     NaN     NaN
11         Y      3     3.0     3.0
12         Y      3     3.0     3.0
13         Y      3     3.0     3.0
14         Y      3     3.0     3.0
15         N      3     NaN     3.0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help and even putting another option :D. One question, for the first output, the last row seems to have NaN  instead of 2. I havent got to try the code yet, and want to check if it was a mistake? :D

Comment: @cyntha no it's expected, there is no Y afterwards

Comment: But the previous assets have treatment and so it should be assigned to group 2 instead. Do I have to do it manually for the last row?

Comment: Then why are row 8/9/10 not part of group1? If you have a specific case it's better to handle it manually. See update for a way to do it.

Comment: Hey thank you I saw you change the code, the reason why I dont assign row8,9,10 to group 1 is because they are 3 assets, if they are only two or less assets that dont have a treatment, then I can assign them to group 1. Thank you so much for that , it now shows the output  that I want :D I will try to understand the code :DD

Comment: Hi @mozway, when the first row starts with 'N' treatment, it does not work as expected(?) The group start with '2' instead of '1'.(?)
Also, if that is okay, I would like to set the first N row that start with 'N' to be set to group 1 if the next row has treatment 'Y' (if cannot that is fine too)